# Are there any digital cameras that show the partial picture mid-exposure?

Tags: long-exposure

Inspired by [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/33779/14375).

Are there any cameras / firmware hacks out there that read the sensor multiple times during a long exposure, and show the partial picture on the screen?

Light-painting should be fun with such a camera :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, actually. The Olympus OM-D E-M5 has a "live bulb" feature which does exactly this.

This shows previews at intervals from half a second to a minute during a bulb-mode exposure.

Comment: This didn't even occur to me while answering the other question, because it avoids the problems inherent there by only working at a very large-scale timeframe. I'm going to update my answer, though.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I found a demo of this feature in action here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rz4g-MFW_t8

Comment: Amazingly, I can't find any mention of it on Olympus America's web site. It's like they don't want you to know how cool they are.

Comment: It's kinda strange, isn't it? Most of the people who buy this model have at least some idea of photography (hint, look at all the "I just bought a Nikon D3100/5100. How do I shot this?" questions here) and would have used film a while ago but they think that people who have no idea about photography are buying them! "They don't even know what live bulb is..."